# Output required in below format in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table with a column called 'Name':

```
NAME
----
F
M
F
M
F
M
F
F
```

How can I show the count of Male and Female in the below format?

```
M  F
3  5
```

Thanks

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've replaced the images with text since they were very simple. Please use text wherever possible.  I also replaced one `M` with an `F` so that the two counts are different, to make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks @William Robertson

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select sum(Case when name = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as "M", 
sum(Case when name = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as "F" 
from my_table
```

Comment: Thanks @gaj is there any alternative way to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot:

```
select * from demo
pivot 
(
  count(name)
  for name in ('F' as f, 'M' as m)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Pivot for this type of solutions.

SELECT 
[M] AS 'MALE', [F] AS 'FEMALE'
FROM
(SELECT NAME 
 FROM #NAME) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(

COUNT(NAME)
 FOR NAME IN ([M], [F])
) AS PivotTable;

Comment: Square brackets and names starting with `#` aren't valid in Oracle.

Comment: This answer have given as per SQL server. As per oracle you can use temporary table  and square bracket replace with ' '.

Comment: OK, but the question was about Oracle.